# How to convert hours in minutes in javascript HH:MM to MM?

Tags: javascript, hour, minute

I want to convert HH:MM to MM I want to use minutes in below code but It can't convert 14:30 to 858 as you can see result here in [***fiddle***](https://jsfiddle.net/arya45/vp76t480/) minutes but it converts 14.3 to minutes if you put 14.3 in fiddle code instead of 14.30.

I am converting hrs. in minutes than I am Lessing 240 minutes from minutes I got How can I convert this hrs. in minute.
below is the code I am trying to convert hours to minutes

***NOTE***: hours can be can be any Time from 0 to 23 it could be 2:30 or it could be 10:30

```
function convertHourstoMinute(hours) {
     return Math.floor(hours * 60);
    }
    let hrs = convertHourstoMinute(14:30); // convert hours into minutes javascript
   console.log( "javascript convert hours to minutes :- " + hrs ); 

            let minutes = hrs * 60;
            console.log(minutes)
            let callback_time = minutes - 240
            console.log(callback_time)
            let call_back = callback_time / 60
            console.log(call_back)
```

Comment: `14:30` is not a valid data in JS. It needs to be string. Or you can use `Date` objects.

Comment: You can use Moment.js to manipulate date and time in JS https://momentjs.com/guides/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few things are incorrect in your code
first you can not pass 14:30 it has to be "14:30"
then 14:30 * 60 is not a valid expression it has to be 14 * 60 + 30
and you dont need Math.floor because you are not passing decimal numbers
if you want to pass decimal number then you have to use 14.5 instead 14:30

```js
function convertH2M(timeInHour){
  var timeParts = timeInHour.split(":");
  return Number(timeParts[0]) * 60 + Number(timeParts[1]);
}

var timeInMinutes = convertH2M("14:30");
console.log(timeInMinutes);
```

If you want to pass decimal numbers instead of 14:30
then this example works

```js
function convertH2M(timeInHour){
  return Math.floor(timeInHour * 60);
}

var timeInMinutes = convertH2M(14.5);
console.log(timeInMinutes);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass variable type of `string`.

Then with ES6 magic which standardises destructuring assignment code could look like this and use `+` sign to convert string to `Number`:

```js
function convertHourstoMinute(str) {
    let [hours, minutes] = str.split(':');
    return (+hours * 60) + (+minutes);
}

console.log( "javascript convert hours to minutes : ", convertHourstoMinute('14:30'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to split the hour and minute and calculate then.

```
function convertHourstoMinute(time) {
 var hour = time.split(':')[0]; //Split returns an array
 var minute = time.split(':')[1];
 return Math.floor(hour * 60) + pareseInt(minute);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use 14:30 in javascript, convert it to string first.

Try this

```js
function convertHourstoMinute(time) {
    var hour = time.split(':')[0]; //Split returns an array
 var minute = time.split(':')[1];
 return parseInt(hour) + Number((minute / 60));
    }
    let hrs = convertHourstoMinute("14:30"); // convert hours into minutes javascript
   console.log( "javascript convert hours to minutes :- " + hrs ); 

            let minutes = hrs * 60;
            console.log(minutes)
            let callback_time = minutes - 240
            console.log(callback_time)
            let call_back = callback_time / 60
            console.log(call_back)
```

But to carry out further date manipulations I suggest you look into momentjs .